# Access check box in static string

Tags: c#, .net, forms

Hi 
i have a problem i cant figure out i know the problem but dont know how to fix it

```
private static string Characters()
    {
        string str = null;

        const string lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå";
        const string upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ";
        const string numeric = "0123456789";

        // connot acces non-static field 'checkLower' in static context
        if (checkLower.Checked)
        {
            str += lower;
        }
        if (checkUpper.Checked)
        {
            str += upper;
        }
        if (checkDigits.Checked)
        {
            str += numeric;
        }

        return str;
    }

    // if i change Characters to non-static this will say cannot access non-staic method 'Characters' in static context
    private static char[] fCharList = Characters().ToCharArray();
```

Comment: Why are you using all of the static modifiers? Remove them all and solve your problem.

Comment: Looking at this code I can't help but wonder who decided that calling `operator + (string a, string b)` with null, "literal" doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: Shouldn't you use 'String.Empty' instead of 'null' to 'str'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 private static string Characters(bool checkLowerChecked, bool checkUpperChecked, bool checkDigitsChecked )
        {
            string str = null;

            const string lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå";
            const string upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÆØÅ";
            const string numeric = "0123456789";

            // connot acces non-static field 'checkLower' in static context
            if (checkLowerChecked)
            {
                str += lower;
            }
            if (checkUpperChecked)
            {
                str += upper;
            }
            if (checkDigitsChecked)
            {
                str += numeric;
            }

            return str;
        }
```

and call

```
Characters(checkLower.Checked, checkUpper.Checked, checkDigits.Checked).ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The static functions/fields can't access member fields, because they're static. Remove the 'static' keyword from both fCharList and Characters if you need to reference checkUpper/Lower etc.